# Adding '/blog/' to only posts and redirects old url to new

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, posts

I am planning to change permalinks to my blog to include '/blog/' to only posts. But issue is with redirect old urls (without /blog/) to new (with /blog/).
Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

enter image description here           Log in to your WordPress  Dashboard: Navigate to your WordPress website's
dashboard by logging in with your credentials.
[image]
**Go to Permalink Settings: In the dashboard, go to "Settings" > "Permalinks."**

```
        Choose Custom Structure: Under the "Common Settings" section, select the 
       "Custom Structure" option.

         Set Custom Structure: In the text box next to "Custom Structure," enter 
         the following: /blog/%postname%/

         This structure will include '/blog/' before the post name in the permalink.

         Save Changes: Click the "Save Changes" button to apply the new permalink structure.
```

Comment: This part is done, but issue comes links to old posts without /blog/ will create 404. How can I add a redirect to "all" single posts to include 'blog'